# drop trigger if exists and create

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, triggers

I would like to check if the trigger exists on [tbl] and create another one. I tried it this way but didn't work. What am I doing wrong?

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.objects WHERE [name] = '[dbo].[trg]' AND [type] = 'TR')
      DROP TRIGGER [dbo].[trg] ON [dbo].[tbl]
GO
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[trg] ON [dbo].[tbl] 
AFTER DELETE
AS
BEGIN
   //
END
GO
```

Answer (score 69, accepted):

The `[name]` field in `sys.objects` will contain only the actual name (i.e. `trg`), *not* including the schema (i.e. `dbo` in this case) or any text qualifiers (i.e. `[` and `]` in this case).

AND, you don't specify the table name for `DROP TRIGGER` since the trigger is an object by itself (unlike indexes). So you need to remove the `ON` clause (which is only used with DDL and Logon triggers).

```sql
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.objects WHERE [name] = N'trg' AND [type] = 'TR')
BEGIN
      DROP TRIGGER [dbo].[trg];
END;
```

Please note that you should prefix the object name string literal with an `N` since the `[name]` field is a `sysname` datatype which equates to `NVARCHAR(128)`.

If you did want to incorporate the schema name, you could use the `OBJECT_ID()` function which does allow for schema names and text qualifiers (you will then need to match against `object_id` instead of `name`):

```sql
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.objects WHERE [object_id] = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[trg]')
               AND [type] = 'TR')
BEGIN
      DROP TRIGGER [dbo].[trg];
END;
```

And to simplify, since the object name needs to be unique within the schema, you really only need to test for its existence. If for some reason a different object type exists with that name, the `DROP TRIGGER` will fail since that other object is, well, not a trigger ;-). Hence, I use the following:

```sql
IF (OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[trg]') IS NOT NULL)
BEGIN
      DROP TRIGGER [dbo].[trg];
END;
```

Comment: hi scrutzky. I get the error : Incorrect syntax near 'dbo'. There is already an object named 'trg' in the database.

Comment: @user3399326 I just updated my answer to address that error. It is the `ON` clause of `DROP TRIGGER` that is causing it.

Comment: add 'TR' to get type : OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[trg]', 'TR')

Answer (score 19):

If you use SQL Server 2016, you can use a shorter variant.

```
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS [dbo].[trg]
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/drop-trigger-transact-sql

Answer (score 0):

Can you try

```
SELECT * FROM sys.objects WHERE [name] = PARSENAME('[dbo].[trg]',1) AND [type] = 'TR'
```

EDIT:

Well srutzky already gave you the answer and well explained, you can parse the name with the help of [PARSENAME](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188006.aspx).

Comment: Why bother with parsename? Just take off the schema. :)

Comment: @SeanLange True, just a bit of extra info won't hurt =)

Answer (score -1):

In case you use SQLite use this syntax:

```
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS trigger_name;
```

More info here: https://www.sqlitetutorial.net/sqlite-trigger/

Comment: This question is specifically tagged as a [tag:sql-server] question. Please avoid posting answers that use another database engine or DBMS, as they can cause confusion for other users that come across the same issue later on.